# how do I get Javascript to recognise an email address?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to give a textfield a dual function. So, if you type, say, 12345, into it, it finds the relevant data. But if you type an email-address, or essentially anything with an XXX@XXX.XXX format, I want the password-field and button to appear. I've been trying to use regex, but for some reason it does not work, and everything is recognised as an email, so even 12345 opens the login-things. Can you help me? I've tried getting the gist into the snippets.

```js
function imgMain() {
  var iDCode = document.getElementById("IDQuery").value;
  var mail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;

  if (iDCode = mail) {
    console.log("this is a mail");
    document.getElementById("passwordDiv").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("loginbuttonDiv").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("SeeSlide").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    console.log("this is not a mail")
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="QueryField">
  <input type="text" id="IDQuery" placeholder="ID Kode">

  <div style="display: none" id=passwordDiv><input type="password" id="passwordfield"><br></div>
  <div style="display: none" id=loginbuttonDiv><button id="login" onclick="login()">log ind</button><br></div>

  <button id="SeeSlide" onclick="imgMain()">Se Slide</button><br>
  <br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Why exactly would you expect a `RegExp` object to evaluate as equal to a string? Have you read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)? (You've also used an [assignment operator `=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment), not a [comparison operator `==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison) in your conditional statement, which would explain why the comparison always evaluates to `true`)

Comment: You need to write `if (mail.test(iDCode))`

Answer (score 0):

user mail.test() with proper regex like so

```
let mail = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
if(mail.test(iDCode)){
      alert("Valid email is required")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this version, it's based on the [w3resource](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php).

```js
function imgMain() {
  var iDCode = document.getElementById("IDQuery").value;
  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

  if (iDCode.match(mailformat)) {
    console.log("this is a mail");
    document.getElementById("passwordDiv").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("loginbuttonDiv").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("SeeSlide").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    console.log("this is not a mail")
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="QueryField">
  <input type="text" id="IDQuery" placeholder="ID Kode">

  <div style="display: none" id=passwordDiv><input type="password" id="passwordfield"><br></div>
  <div style="display: none" id=loginbuttonDiv><button id="login" onclick="login()">log ind</button><br></div>

  <button id="SeeSlide" onclick="imgMain()">Se Slide</button><br>
  <br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the .validate function. It works really great for checking login forms.
The function could look like the following:

```
$("#IDQuery").validate({
    rules: {
        email:
            {required: true, email: true},
        password:
            {required: true}
        },
    messages: {
        email:
        {required: 'Please enter a E-mail',
        email: 'Please enter a valid E-mail'},
        password:{required: 'Please enter a password'}
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `if` statement you have `if (iDCode = mail)`.

This **re-assigns** the value of `mail` to the variable `iDCode`. So the `if` effectively becomes `if(mail)` which is *always* true, because RegEx objects are truthy.

You should instead be checking if the input *matches* the regex, using either `mail.test(iDCode)` or `iDCode.match(mail)`

Answer (score 0):

Few different ways. You can send an email to that address and check whether it bounces back or you can use PHP (I doubt you want to do this since your question is JavaScript) and send an email and then have them confirm it on the web address. Honestly, PHP is the best way to do this but since you're using JS you can try this from https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php:

```
function ValidateEmail(mail) {
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(myForm.emailAddr.value)) {
    return (true)
 }
 alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
 return (false)
}
```

This works because we are checking all the invalid characters that are in an email address. If the input field contains any of those characters, its invalid.

Try Googling the answer. There are lots of information:
https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEB_enUS865US865&ei=bn9dXuefDanJ0PEPofOHyAg&q=javacsript+check+email+address&oq=javacsript+check+email+address&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71l8.2549.3358..3533...0.2..0.0.0.......12....1..gws-wiz.........23%3A11-12j24%3A11-2.1hEMZpGGmWs&ved=0ahUKEwjnjr7N4vznAhWpJDQIHaH5AYkQ4dUDCAw&uact=5&safe=active&ssui=on